# Class which inherits from abstract class which implements interface, and loading this reflectively

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection, interface, abstract-class

I have an Interface named IPlugin. This is implemented in an abstract class which is called TimerClass. There is then a class named Test which inherits from TimerClass.

The Test class is in it's own dll, and is loaded by reflection.

This works perfectly well if i don't use the TimerClass (just implement IPlugin in Test).

My code which loads the Test class reflectively as an interface (IPlugin) looks like this:

```
    private IPlugin GetInterface(Assembly assembly)
    {
        IPlugin PluginFound = null;
        var iPluginType = typeof (IPlugin);

        var types = assembly.GetExportedTypes();

        foreach (var type in types)
            if (iPluginType.IsAssignableFrom(type))
            {
                var operation = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IPlugin;

                if (operation != null)
                {
                    PluginFound = operation;
                    break;
                }
            }
        return PluginFound;
    }
```

This part of the code: `var operation = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IPlugin;` crashes when the Test class is loaded.

At first i thought it could be that it tries to load the Abstract class TimerClass, but this seems far fetch since this class is not implemented in the same DLL. I also debugged it, and looked at the assembly, and to me it seems that the correct class is loaded...

Can anyone tell me why this is happening, and if there is a solution that i am not seeing?

Comment: Can you provide a exception message and call stack info you've got?

Comment: It is inside a bunch of threads.. if i am to find it, you'll have to wait for a bit and i'll have to implement exception policies... :) I was hoping to do that later.. so any guesses or hunches is very much appriciated

Comment: Did you try to use Activator.CreateInstance(NameSpaceOfType.Type)?

Comment: The type in types, which is recieved from assembly.GetExportedTypes() gets the namespace, the fullname and all the references to the abstract classes and the IPlugin...... when loading the type, it is not really a type as in typeof, and contains namespaces and all information needed. Switching to NameSpaceOfType.Type would reduce the amount information...

Comment: For Instance, If your timer class has no parameterless contructor it will fail.

Comment: My TimerClass has no constructor (which creates the default one, without parameters)... hmm.. my test class however, has an empty constructor... and does some stuff... could that have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is embarresing....

The reason for it to fail was that the TimerClass had a property which defined the interval of the timer. This stops and starts the timer, so when this is called before the timer is created... well.... Then it crashes....

I am so sorry to have wasted your time, but thank you so much for helping me out!